# Ordering duplicates in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm using a function that counts duplicates of strings in an array and displays how many times each occurs. The problem is that it spits them out in any old function. The output looks like this:

> a comes --> 22 times abortions comes --> 1 times about comes --> 3
>   times acknowledgment comes --> 1 times actually comes --> 2 times
>   affairs comes --> 1 times ago comes --> 1 times aid comes --> 1 times
>   all comes --> 4 times allowed comes --> 1 times ally comes --> 1 times
>   almost comes --> 1 times alone comes --> 1 times already comes --> 1
>   times also comes --> 2 times always comes --> 1 times america comes
>   --> 1 times american comes --> 1 times americans comes --> 2 times an comes --> 3 times analogies comes --> 1 times and comes --> 46 times
>   another comes --> 1 times april comes --> 1 times are comes --> 16
>   times area comes --> 1 time

What I need it to do is put these outputs into another array, and sort them so that I can iterate through it and have the output looking like:

> 'a' comes 997 times  'and' comes 439 times 'hello' comes 398 times 'highboy'
>   comes 147 times 'excellent' 99 times 'massive' 44 times 'arsonist' 30 times
>   'Jenny' comes 19 times 'purple' comes 6 times

... and so on.

This is the function, I am using:

```
function count() {

    var words = ['hi', 'hi', 'hello', 'smack']; 

    words.sort();

    var current = null;
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i] != current) {
            if (cnt > 0) {
                document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times<br>');
            }
            current = words[i];
            cnt = 1;
        } else {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    if (cnt > 0) {
        document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times');
    }

}

count();
```

I don't want to use it by calling count() and having a bunch of `document.write()`'s, I want to pack it all into another array that I can get all these values out in order. I hope that makes sense.

I know that I have to create another array, say `var sorted_array`; But how can I get this information that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the problem in two, first create a data structure that holds the duplicates and their count, then transform this data structure into an array sorted by occurences. Then you can do whatever you need with the result.

```
var occurences = ['hi', 'hi', 'hello', 'smack', 'smack', 'smack'].reduce(function (res, word) {
    res[word] = (res[word] || 0) + 1
    return res;
}, {});

var duplicates = Object.keys(occurences).map(function (k) {
    return {word: k, count: occurences[k]};
})
//make sure that we only keep duplicates
.filter(function(item) { return item.count > 1; })

//sort them by count descendent
.sort(function (a, b) { return b.count - a.count; })

//display the words and their count in the console
.forEach(function (dup) { console.log(dup.word, dup.count); });
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be like this  (to avoid multiple document.write's)

```
function count() {

    var words = ['hi', 'hi', 'hello', 'smack'];

    words.sort();

    var current = null;
    var cnt = 0;

    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i] != current) {
            if (cnt > 0) {
                output.push(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times<br />');
            }
            current = words[i];
            cnt = 1;
        } else {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    if (cnt > 0) {
        output.push(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times<br />');

        output.sort();  // sort by word, not by how many occurrences of a word

        document.write(output.join());
        /*alert(output);*/
    }
}

count();
```

Comment: How are you adressing the ordering issue?

Comment: I didn't (missed that part in the question), I solved _multiple document write's_ ... I will update my answer

Comment: I cannot get this to work, on my machine. It still comes out unordered and it's even skipping over some altogether now. http://jsfiddle.net/UJ73j/

Comment: And you can't use document.write in fiddle, that's why I removed the dot in between, to not get error (in fiddle demo)

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object with the words as keys, and the count as the value, then you can output it anyway you'd like :

```
function count(words) {
    var o = {}, a= [];

    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) 
        o[words[i]] = words[i] in o ? o[words[i]]+1 : 1;

    for (var key in o) 
        a.push(key + ' comes --> ' + o[key] + ' times<br>');

    return a.sort().join('');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A98rS/3/)

Comment: Why are you sorting the array on every iteration? Actually, why are you even sorting words just to get a count map?

Comment: @plalx - I'm sorting them to get them in order, why else! You are right, the sorting should happen outside the loop, edited that.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, what's the point of putting them in order? You have no control over the for loop iteration and nothing specifies in the spec that keys will be iterated in the order they were added to the object. `Object.keys(o).sort().forEach(...)` would make sense however.

Comment: @plalx - Who cares, your answer has been accepted anyway! I did however change it just to make sure you didn't get your panties in a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kenZ/) for you, hope this helps.

```
var words = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz'],
    word,
    key,
    wordCount = {},
    sortedWordCountKeys,
    pluralize,
    output;

for (word in words) {
    wordCount[words[word]] = wordCount[words[word]] ?
        wordCount[words[word]] + 1 :
        1;
}

sortedWordCountKeys = Object.keys(wordCount).sort(function(a, b) {
    return wordCount[b] - wordCount[a];
});

for (key in sortedWordCountKeys) {
    word = sortedWordCountKeys[key];
    pluralize = wordCount[word] > 1 ? 's' : '';
    output = wordCount[word] + ' occurence' + pluralize + ' of "' + word + '" found.';
    console.log(output);
}
```

Or maybe you prefer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am3L5/)

```
var words = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz'],
    i,
    word,
    wordCount = {},
    sortedWordCountKeys,
    pluralize,
    output;

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    wordCount[words[i]] = wordCount[words[i]] ?
        wordCount[words[i]] + 1 :
        1;
}

sortedWordCountKeys = Object.keys(wordCount).sort(function(a, b) {
    return wordCount[b] - wordCount[a];
});

for (i = 0; i < sortedWordCountKeys.length; i++) {
    word = sortedWordCountKeys[i];
    pluralize = wordCount[word] > 1 ? 's' : '';
    output = wordCount[word] + ' occurence' + pluralize + ' of "' + word + '" found.';
    console.log(output);
}
```

Or maybe even this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWcB2/)

```
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel lacus justo. Quisque eu lorem at metus condimentum iaculis a a risus. Proin vitae ligula iaculis, vehicula ligula quis, luctus ipsum. Nulla consectetur eros in nisi tempus, sit amet mollis eros accumsan. Duis dignissim ornare magna, vel elementum arcu accumsan ut. Curabitur at ligula a dui pretium placerat at eu nisi. Donec a tellus tempor, venenatis tortor nec, auctor nisi. Sed congue arcu sit amet tortor vulputate vulputate. Etiam sed odio eleifend, rhoncus risus nec, porttitor libero. Etiam placerat mauris vitae felis egestas, in tristique velit condimentum. Nam odio elit, congue eget semper vel, lacinia vel dolor. Duis tempor enim diam, vel auctor tortor tincidunt eget. Praesent congue quam mi, et lobortis ipsum tempus nec. Duis blandit mi et facilisis adipiscing. Etiam ut tellus ut dolor convallis consectetur a id nulla.',
    i,
    words = text.split(' '),
    word,
    wordCount = {},
    sortedWordCountKeys,
    pluralize,
    output;

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i]
       .replace(/\./g, '')
       .replace(/\,/g, '');

    wordCount[words[i]] = wordCount[words[i]] ?
        wordCount[words[i]] + 1 :
        1;
}

sortedWordCountKeys = Object.keys(wordCount).sort(function(a, b) {
    return wordCount[b] - wordCount[a];
});

for (i = 0; i < sortedWordCountKeys.length; i++) {
    word = sortedWordCountKeys[i];
    pluralize = wordCount[word] > 1 ? 's' : '';
    output = wordCount[word] + ' occurence' + pluralize + ' of "' + word + '" found.';
    console.log(output);
}
```